# парсинг json в uitableview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, cocoa

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import ObjectMapper
import AlamofireObjectMapper

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var array = [Languages]()
let URL = "https://api.hh.ru/locales?host=hh.ru"


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    Alamofire.request(.GET, URL).responseArray { (response: Response<[Languages], NSError>) in

        self.array = response.result.value!

    }


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return array.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    var a = array[indexPath.row]

    cell.nameLabelField?.text = a.name
    cell.idLabelField?.text = a.id
    cell.currentLabel?.text = "\(a.current)"



    return cell
    }
}
```

[Пользуюсь этим AlamofireObjectMapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper)

не могу вернуть данные в ячейку 
скорее всего очень сильно туплю помогите плиз

Language

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import ObjectMapper
import AlamofireObjectMapper


class Languages: Mappable {
    var current: NSNumber?
    var id: String?
    var name: String?

required init?(_ map: Map){

}
func mapping(map: Map) {
    current <- map["current"]
    id <- map["id"]
    name <- map["name"]

}
}
```

Comment: так что именно не получается? после парсинга объект пустой, или объект приходит нормально но cell пустой?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko объект приходит нормально но cell пустой

Comment: то есть, если в cellForRowAtIndexPath сделать print(a.name) например, то имя там будет?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko нету(

Comment: Вы можете определиться что у вас сломано? только что сказали, что объект после парсинга нормальный, сейчас говорите, что пустой. Давайте еще раз. приходит json, преобразуется в объект класса Languages, потом на основании объекта создается ячейка. в каком месте происходит сбой?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko 
self.array = response.result.value!
            for i in self.array {
                print(i.name)
            }
name  есть 
он опциональный в консоле
в ячейку он не проходи

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko сам массив если во viewdidload пробывать принтить он будет [ ]

Comment: а обращение к серверу у вас синхронное? и где вызывается функция mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

после приема данных обновить таблицу, я забыл ((

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, URL).responseArray { (response: Response<[Languages], NSError>) in

self.array = response.result.value!
self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
     .responseJSON { response in
         print(response.request)  // original URL request
         print(response.response) // URL response
         print(response.data)     // server data
         print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

         if let JSON = response.result.value {
             print("JSON: \(JSON)")
         }
     }
```

Смотри что в JSON приходит и в зависимости массив это или словарь делай парсинг.

если приходит что то вроде  этого

```
"data": [
 {
  "id": "2",
 }
]
```

То вот подходящий парсинг

```
if let blogs = JSON["data"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                        for blog in blogs {

                            if let id = blog["id"] as? String {
                                print(id)
                            }
                         }
}
```

Удачи.